# Foreign key constraints in Android using SQLite? on Delete cascade

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two tables: tracks and waypoints, a track can have many waypoints, but a waypoint is assigned to only 1 track.

In the way points table I have a column called "trackidfk" which inserts the track_ID once a track is made, however I have not setup Foreign Key constraints on this column.

When I delete a track I want to delete the assigned waypoints, is this possible?. I read about using Triggers but I don't think they are supported in Android.

To create the waypoints table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME 
                + " (" 
                + _ID         + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                + LONGITUDE   + " INTEGER," 
                + LATITUDE    + " INTEGER," 
                + TIME        + " INTEGER,"
                + TRACK_ID_FK + " INTEGER"
                + " );"
              );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Foreign key constraints with on delete cascade are supported, but you need to enable them.
I just added the following to my *SQLOpenHelper*, which seems to do the trick.

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```

I declared my referencing column as follows.

```
mailbox_id INTEGER REFERENCES mailboxes ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Which means it only works since Android 2.2 Froyo which has SQLite 3.6.22

Comment: @RedPlanet - it's because the only time this constraint is enforced is when something is written to the database. (You can't break this constraint if all you do is read from the db) Also, Phil, instead of the onOpen method, it's probably better to do it in the onConfigure method. Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)

Comment: Google recommends writting `PRAGMA` statements in [`onConfigure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) but it requires API level 16 (Android 4.1), and by then you can simply call [`setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12531927/1402846).

Comment: One may also need to consider enabling foreign key constraints in `onCreate`/`onDowngrade`/`onUpgrade`, which are before `onOpen`. See [source code in Android 4.1.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java/#240).

Comment: You don't need to call super, the default implementation is empty.

Comment: @Intrications  I have created tables having foreign key but i haven't enable them using Pragma command and my tables are created successfully!

Comment: @Natix including the call to super ensures correct functionality if an intermediate class is introduced between the implemented class and its parent.

Answer (score 56):

Since Android 4.1 (API 16) [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) supports:

```
public void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled (boolean enable)
```

Answer (score 27):

As the post from e.shishkin says from API 16 up you should enable foreign key constraints in the `SqLiteOpenHelper.onConfigure(SqLiteDatabase)` method using the `db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean)`

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Never too old of a question to answer with a more complete answer.

```
@Override public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(db);
    }
    mOpenHelperCallbacks.onOpen(mContext, db);
}

private void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabledPreJellyBean(db);
    } else {
        setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabledPostJellyBean(db);
    }
}

private void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabledPreJellyBean(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabledPostJellyBean(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Whatever @phil mentioned is good. But you can use another default method available in 
     Database itself to set the foreignkey. That is setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true).

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;"); 
              //(OR)
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled (true)
    }
}
```

For Docs refer [SQLiteDatabase.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean))

Comment: The documentation you posted suggests: 

`A good time to call this method is right after calling openOrCreateDatabase(File, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) or in the onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase) callback.`

So instead of `onOpen`, `onConfigure` seems to be the right place.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think SQLite supports this out of the box. What I'm doing in my apps is:

1. Create transaction
2. Delete detail data (waypoints in your example)
3. Delete master data (tracks in your example)
4. Commit transaction on success

That way I'm sure that either all the data is deleted or none.

Comment: But are you deleting from both tables using one method?

Comment: Yes, I went pretty much along with the Notes sample from the API. When I am to delete what would be a track in your case, I create the transaction, delete track and waypoints and commit the transaction. That's all in one go.

Answer (score 4):

Triggers are supported by android and that type of cascade delete is not supported by sqlite.  An example of using triggers on android can be found [here](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/).  Though using transactions as Thorsten stated is probably just as easy as a trigger.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite version in android 1.6 is 3.5.9 so it doesn't support foreign keys...

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html
"This document describes the support for SQL foreign key constraints introduced in SQLite version 3.6.19."

In Froyo it's SQLite version 3.6.22, so ...

EDIT: 
to see sqlite version : adb shell sqlite3 -version

Comment: So is there any way to forces such constraints.. I mean is there any way to upgrade sqlite version.. because we must have to support out software version to android 2.1 which has sqlite version 3.5.9 as above

Comment: No, you have to handle everything by yourself :(

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys with "on delete cascade" are supported in SQLite in Android 2.2 and up. But be careful when using them: sometimes an error is reported when firing up one foreign key on one column, but the real problem lies in either another column foreign key constraint in the child table, or some other table thet references this table.

Looks like SQLite checks all constraints when firing up one of them. It is actually mentioned in the documentation. DDL versus DML constraint checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Room, do as shown below.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
    .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        // Called when the database has been opened.
        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            //True to enable foreign key constraints
            db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)
        }

        // Called when the database is created for the first time. 
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
        }
    }).build()
```