# Creating foreign key constraints in ORMLite under SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

As it is not possible to add foreign keys using an "ALTER TABLE" statement in SQLite, I am stuck on how to configure my database to enforce valid foreign keys, or perform cascaded deletes without explicit code overhead.

Anybody got an idea how to accomplish this with ORMLite under SQLite?

Comment: I found the getCreateTableStatements() solution, and it works like a charm. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to configure my database to enforce valid foreign keys, or perform cascaded deletes without explicit code overhead.

ORMLite supports a `columnDefinition="..."` field in the `@DatabaseFiled` annotation @Timo.  I'm not sure if it provides you the power you need but it does allow you to have custom column definitions.

> [http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnDefinition()](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnDefinition%28%29)

If it doesn't then I'm afraid that you may have to create your database outside of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) in this case.  You can use `TableUtils.getCreateTableStatements()` to get the statements necessary to create the table and add the enforcement and cascade statements that you need.  Here are the [javadocs for that method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#getCreateTableStatements%28com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: Could you please post example, how use columnDefinition with foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 22):

To elaborate on Gray's awesome answer (for anyone else who stumbles upon this question), you can use the `columnDefinition` annotation to define a foreign key constraint **and** cascading delete.

First, foreign key constraints were added to SQLite in 3.6.19, which means you can use them in Android 2.2 or higher (since 2.2 ships with SQLite 3.6.22).  However, foreign key constraints are **not enabled by default**. To enable them, use the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade).

Here's an example using the `columnDefinition` annotation. This assumes your table/object you are referencing is called `parent` which has a primary key of `id`.

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true,
      columnDefinition = "integer references parent(id) on delete cascade")
private Parent parent;
```

Note that the format for the String value does not include the column name (that's what the [columnName](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnName%28%29) annotation is for).

Answer (score -3):

I think the next link can be helpful:

http://mueller.panopticdev.com/2011/03/ormlite-and-android.html

in short, you can set it as :

```
public class Person {
...
@DatabaseField(columnName = "organization_id", canBeNull = false)
private Organization m_organization;
```

This way, Person has a foreign key to Organization, and the key it uses on Organization is "organization_id" .

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not explain how to create a constraint with cascaded delete.

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt I actually don't remember this answer and the question. Sorry.