# SQlite - create table with FK error

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am trying to create table with Foreign Key, but Netbeans is giving me SQLite exepction - syntax error:

```
AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "_id": syntax error: CREATE TABLE customer1 _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, info REAL, customer_a INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (customer_a) REFERENCES customer4 (_id);
```

Whilst, table customer4 in time of creating table customer1 exists, I am still getting syntax error. I have been looking on the web and I haven't found anything stating, I have bad syntax. Do you see where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis around your column names. You need to do something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE customer1 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 name TEXT, info REAL, customer_a INTEGER REFERENCES customer4(_id));
```

Comment: Thanks so, I should have added brackets and I should have merged both "customer_a INTEGER" and "FOREIGN KEY (customer_a) REFERENCES customer4(_id)" into "customer_a INTEGER REFERENCES customer4(_id)"?

Answer (score 0):

Which android version do you use?
Foreign keys are only available since Android 2.2.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade/3404279#3404279)

Comment: Thank you, I am using 2.2 and higher, so it will work OK I think