# Create a SQLite Database in Android with Foreign Keys?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is this supported?  I'm attempting to create a table but am getting a syntax error when compiling.

```
private static final String ROOM_CREATE =
        "create table room (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        "facility integer not null, FORIEGN KEY (facility) REFERENCES facility(_id));";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key constraints in Android using SQLite? on Delete cascade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade)

Comment: It is possible. Syntax error from compiling could be different one, can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: FORIEGN KEY...syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some great answers, particularly @sfratini for spotting the typo in the FOREIGN keyword. Can I also recommend that you should troubleshoot your SQL statements by using a command line client, such as the "Precompiled Binaries For Windows" (see http://sqlite.org/download.html). That way, you can validate the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements before you put them into your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create foreign keys, but you have to enable enforcement in SQLite with

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo in the SQL:

FORIEGN -> FOREIGN

Answer (score -1):

The `facility` in `facility(_id)` must refers to table name. You are defining same name to column also. Please change table name and try again.