# Does android SQLite database support key constraints?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm reading the book [Android Database Programming](http://www.packtpub.com/android-practical-tutorial-database-programming/book)

And I'm wondering to know if what said here is correct:

**for those who are well versed in SQL programming and database 
schemas, you might be wondering if it's possible to add triggers and key constraints 
to your SQLite database schemas. The answer is, "yes, you can use triggers but no, 
you cannot use foreign key constraints."**

and also:

**remember that Android's SQLite database doesn't support key constraints**

This is strange for me, because I know that I can use (from SQLite 3.6.19)

`setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled` method for enabling FK constraints, or I can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266882/1584654)

I'm confused. So the question is: Why the book aforementioned said that FK are not supported? Considering that at time of publishing (June 2012), Android 4.0.3 (SQLite 3.7.4) was already released.

Comment: FK constraints work just fine in my 2.2+ apps, so I suppose he might just be completely wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many reasons for the author not to mention that (EG: the book could have been written when the current version of the SQLite was older than 3.6.19 and published later), but it doesn't make any sense to answer/guess that in StackOverflow.

What it does make sense to mention is the fact that Foreign Key support was added in 3.6.19 but it doesn't just work out of the blue. There are some things to take into consideration in order to use them:

- SQLite version should be >= `3.6.19`
- The library must be compiled with neither `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` or `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` defined
- Support for FK must be enabled by the application at runtime, using the `PRAGMA foreign_keys` command

It should also be noted that FK constraints are disabled by default for backwards compatibility. So you should take care of enabling them for each database connection.

You can read more about this in the [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).

Comment: In some points in the book, the author talk about API Level 11,(Honeycomb) that uses SQLite 3.7.4.

Comment: Interesting. Anyway, having SQLite >= 3.6.19 is only one of the 3 requirements to work with FK. He still could have compiled his version with the `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` flag.