# Are foreign keys supported in the Android SDK implementation of SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Oddly, I cannot find an answer to this question. I'm doing table designs with the assumption that I'll be able to use foreign keys in my Android app. If I can't using the default sdk, are there other options? Can I gen a build with the pragma and include it as a lib?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> ...support for SQL foreign key constraints [was] introduced in SQLite version 3.6.19

According to [the SO question serving as our repository of version info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android), API Level 8+ should have a new-enough SQLite version to offer foreign key support. That should be enough for most developers.

Comment: That says "foreign key constraints."  Foreign key support (in the sense of being able to create joins) has probably been available long before that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm preferring to be conservative in my interpretation of the question. When I think "foreign keys", I usually think of "foreign key constraints". But your point is valid -- I am fairly certain that `JOIN` has been around in SQLite longer than Android has been around in general.

Comment: Thanks for the API Level info. Do you know if foreign key support is enabled by default. My reading of the SQLite doco suggests that it is not.

Comment: @JohnnyRaved: "Do you know if foreign key support is enabled by default" -- hmmmm... `setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled()` was added to `SQLiteDatabase` in API Level 16, so it's at least possible to use them starting then. Prior to that, [you need to execute the `PRAGMA` yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3266882/115145).