# Cant create table with foreign key android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

So this is how i create my tables

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "find.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

    public static final String TABELA_PERCURSOS = "percursos";
    public static final String PERCURSO_ID = "_id";
    public static final String CIDADE = "cidade";
    public static final String CATEGORIA = "categoria";
    public static final String INTERESSE = "interesse";


    public static final String TABELA_CIDADES = "cidades";
    public static final String ID_CIDADES = "_id";
    public static final String NOME_CIDADES = "nome";

    public static final String TABELA_CATEGORIAS = "categorias";
    public static final String ID_CATEGORIAS = "_id";
    public static final String NOME_CATEGORIAS = "nome_categorias";

    public static final String TABELA_INTERESSES = "interesses";
    public static final String ID_INTERESSES = "_id";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    public static final String DESCRICAO = "descricao";
    public static final String NOME_INTERESSE = "nome_interesse";
    public static final String ESTADO = "estado"; //0 se nao visitado; 1 se visitado

    private static final String CREATE_TABELA_CIDADES = "create table " + TABELA_CIDADES + "( " + ID_CIDADES
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NOME_CIDADES + " text not null unique )";

    private static final String CREATE_TABELA_CATEGORIAS = "create table " + TABELA_CATEGORIAS + "( " + ID_CATEGORIAS
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NOME_CATEGORIAS + " text not null unique )";

    private static final String CREATE_TABELA_INTERESSES = "create table " + TABELA_INTERESSES + "( " + ID_INTERESSES
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + LATITUDE + " integer not null unique, " + LONGITUDE + " integer not null unique, "
            + DESCRICAO + " text not null unique, " + NOME_INTERESSE + " text not null unique, " + ESTADO + " integer)";


    public static final String CREATE_TABELA_PERCURSOS = "create table " + TABELA_PERCURSOS + "( "
            + PERCURSO_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + CIDADE + " integer not null, "
            + CATEGORIA + " integer not null, "
            + INTERESSE + " integer), " +
            "foreign key (" + INTERESSE + ") references " + TABELA_INTERESSES + "(" + ID_INTERESSES + ")";

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABELA_CIDADES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABELA_CATEGORIAS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABELA_INTERESSES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABELA_PERCURSOS);
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_CIDADES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_CATEGORIAS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_INTERESSES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_PERCURSOS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

and this is the errors I got:

```
**E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ",": syntax error**
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.nagisa.find, PID: 3627
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nagisa.find/com.example.nagisa.find.MainActivity}: **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table percursos( _id integer primary key autoincrement, cidade integer not null, categoria integer not null, interesse integer), foreign key (interesse) references interesses(_id)
      at **android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table percursos( _id integer primary key autoincrement, cidade integer not null, categoria integer not null, interesse integer), foreign key (interesse) references interesses(_id)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
      at com.example.nagisa.find.DataHelper.onCreate(DataHelper.java:73)
      at com.example.nagisa.find.DataHelper.onUpgrade(DataHelper.java:83)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
      at com.example.nagisa.find.DataHelper.myCursor(DataHelper.java:143)
      at com.example.nagisa.find.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Move `db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");` to be the very first thing you execute on your `SQLiteDatabase`, before creating any tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just had to relocate two parentesis and move Pragma, and it worked. Tank you so much!

Comment: Would like to give you some star but dont know where xD thank you again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign key constraints in Android using SQLite? on Delete cascade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade)